# where is the log file for Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

I am using the Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper and the engine has a "log" function.

Here is some example code:

```
public class BootstrapperApplicationWrapper : BootstrapperApplication
{
    protected override void Run()
    {
        Engine.Log(LogLevel.Standard, string.Format("Command.Action : {0} - Command.Display : {1}", this.Command.Action.ToString(), this.Command.Display.ToString()));

        base.Run();
    }
}
```

Where are the logs written?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test right now but it should be possible to simply run your bootstrapped installer with command line parameter:

```
-log <path_to_log>
```

That way you are driving where the log will be created. Some further reading can be found [here](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Running-Burn-driven-installer-in-quiet-mode-command-line-parameters-td5913001.html), scroll down a bit to Rob Mensching's answer:

> -l, -log = log to a specific file (default is controled by bundle developer)

By "default is controlled by developer" he means that you can use `<Log>` element in your bundle wxs and define default path to log file, for more info see [documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/log.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. By default the logs are written to this location "**%localappdata%\temp**".
2. This is controlled by the Burn variable "*WixBundleLog*".
3. You can override the default logging by using the [LOG ELEMENT](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/log.html)